# match_parent within wrap_content layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to find documentation or guidelines as to behaviour of a UI component with the layout_width/layout_height set to match_parent within a ViewHolder of layout_width/layout_height of wrap_content.

So for instance, what is the EXPECTED result of the following layout?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
     />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the description [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html), the layout of your example would depend on what you put inside the LinearLayout. That content would expand to fill all available vertical space within the parent RelativeLayout. By default, the LinearLayout would be positioned at the top left of the parent RelativeLayout